# How can I delete a location?

Tags: swift

The user can save his position and save it in a list.
The problem is that when the user deletes a location seems to work, but if you close the app and open it up again you will see the locations that you have deleted before...
I leave the location file and the LocationsStorage files. 
Thanks for your help

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class Location: Codable {
  static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
  }()

  var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
  }

  let latitude: Double
  let longitude: Double
  let date: Date
  let dateString: String
  let description: String

  init(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, date: Date, descriptionString: String) {
    latitude =  location.latitude
    longitude =  location.longitude
    self.date = date
    dateString = Location.dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    description = descriptionString
  }

  convenience init(visit: CLVisit, descriptionString: String) {
    self.init(visit.coordinate, date: visit.arrivalDate, descriptionString: descriptionString)
  }
}
```

Now the LocationsStorage file

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationsStorage {
  static let shared = LocationsStorage()

  var locations: [Location]
  private let fileManager: FileManager
  private let documentsURL: URL

  init() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    documentsURL = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)    
    self.fileManager = fileManager

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

    let locationFilesURLs = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL,
                                                                 includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    locations = locationFilesURLs.compactMap { url -> Location? in
      guard !url.absoluteString.contains(".DS_Store") else {
        return nil
      }
      guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        return nil
      }
      return try? jsonDecoder.decode(Location.self, from: data)
    }.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
  }

  func saveLocationOnDisk(_ location: Location) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let timestamp = location.date.timeIntervalSinceNow
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(timestamp)")

    let data = try! encoder.encode(location)
    try! data.write(to: fileURL)

    locations.append(location)

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .newLocationSaved, object: self, userInfo: ["location": location])
  }

  func saveCLLocationToDisk(_ clLocation: CLLocation) {
    let currentDate = Date()
    AppDelegate.geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) { placemarks, _ in
      if let place = placemarks?.first {
        let location = Location(clLocation.coordinate, date: currentDate, descriptionString: "\(place)")
        self.saveLocationOnDisk(location)
      }
    }
  }
}

extension Notification.Name {
  static let newLocationSaved = Notification.Name("newLocationSaved")
}
```

Comment: You never delete any of the files you saved. Try deleting them at an appropriate time?

Comment: I delete them inside an other file -> https://pastebin.com/SChrJ1bt

Comment: You are not calling `saveCLLocationToDisk` after delete right?

Comment: Right but I can't figure out how to delete the locations from the disk

Answer (score 1):

To be able to delete a location on disk you have to change the `LocationsStorage`class.

At the moment the file name is created by a timestamp depending on the current date. This makes it (rather) impossible to identify the file name from a given location.

The most significant change is to replace the line

```
let timestamp = location.date.timeIntervalSinceNow
```

with

```
let timestamp = location.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

and to add a file extension to the file name

```
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(timestamp).json")
```

The timestamp depending on `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` makes it possible to identify the file name from the `date` property in `Location`.

The file extension is not crucial but a good practice and you can filter the location files by the extension

```
locations = locationFilesURLs.compactMap { url -> Location? in
    guard url.pathExtension == "json" else {
        return nil
    }
...
```

Now you can add a method to delete a location from disk

```
func deleteLocation(_ location : Location) {
    let timestamp = location.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(timestamp).json")
    do {
        try self.fileManager.removeItem(at: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

To delete a location in the table view

```
 if editingStyle == .delete{
    let locationToDelete = LocationsStorage.shared.locations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    LocationsStorage.shared.deleteLocation(locationToDelete)
 }
```

Comment: The part where I filter the location files by the extension, I have to put it insiede my LocationsStorage? I'm right?

Comment: Actually replace `guard !url.absoluteString.contains(".DS_Store") else {` with `guard url.pathExtension == "json" else {`

Comment: The method to delte a location from a disk I have to call it in PlacesTableViewController? Above my if editingStyle == .delte{... ?

Comment: I'v already read it but I can't understand where ot properly place it... when I'v replaced the code in your second comment I recive an unresolved identifier in try! data.write(to: fileURL)

Comment: The `deleteLocation` method must be added in `LocationsStorage`. And the part after `editingStyle == .delete` must be put into `tableView: commit: forRowAt:`

Comment: Ok I'v dove all. But I get an error in the LocationsStorage file. In the part "try! data.write(to: fileURL)" i get the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'data'; did you mean 'Data'?"

Comment: My addition doesn't contain `data`. Of course `func deleteLocation(` must be on the top level of the class like the other `func`tions. And check the balance of the braces `{ }`.

Comment: I can't find the error, the balance of the braces seems good. This is the LocatiosStorage updated file: https://pastebin.com/uUqN7mpP

Comment: Please, please learn to read code. The line `let data = try! encoder.encode(location)` is missing.